# Form data is not coming in

Tags: python, html

fasapi constantly gives the error :

> “POST /login HTTP/1.1” 422 Unprocessable

Entity when trying to get the code from the form this way.
on the site the error looks like this:

```
{ "detail": 
  [ { "loc"  : [ "body", "username"] 
    , "msg"  : "field required"
    , "type" : "value_error.missing"
    } 
  , { "loc " : [ "body", "password"] 
    , "msg"  : "field required"
    , "type" : "value_error.missing"
    } 
  ] 
}
```

```
@router.get('/')
async def get_base_page(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})

@app.post("/login")
async def login(request: Request, signup_username: str = Form(None), signup_email: str = Form(None), signup_password: str = Form(None), login_email: str = Form(None), login_password: str = Form(None)):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("login.html", {"request": request})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Сокращатель ссылок</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', path='/login.css') }}"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div class="main">        
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk" aria-hidden="true"> 
     
        <div class="signup"> 
            <form action="/login" method="post"> 
                <label for="chk" aria-hidden="true">Sign up</label> 
                <input type="text" name="signup_username" id="signup_username" placeholder="User name">  
                <input type="email" name="signup_email" id="signup_email" placeholder="Email"> 
                <input type="password" name="signup_password" id="signup_password" placeholder="Password"> 
                <button>Sign up</button> 
            </form> 
        </div> 
     
        <div class="login"> 
            <form action="/login" method="post">  
                <label for="chk" aria-hidden="true">Login</label> 
                <input type="email" name="login_email" id="login_email" placeholder="Email"> 
                <input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password" placeholder="Password"> 
                <button>Login</button> 
            </form> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I tried everything I could, asked everyone I know and more

Comment: Why do you have parameters `signup_username`, `signup_email`, `signup_password` in your definition for the `/login` route? You are not sending any fields with those names from your login form, those are part of your sign-up form only.

Comment: the fact is that registration and login occur on the same page

Comment: Not sure if that makes that much sense to begin with. Not sure how things work in python, but to me it looks like it complains because you are not sending _all_ the parameters you specified there ...?

Comment: Yes, I want to accept all the data for further validation and, in theory, the None parameter in Python should indicate that an empty value can come, but judging by the error, something is not working as it should

Comment: Not sure why the error message would talk about `username` and `password` to begin with, none of your parameters are actually named that - they are all prefixed with either `signup_` or `login_`. Are those errors even coming from the system itself, or have you implemented part of your own validation already?

Comment: I also find the errors regarding non-existent parameters strange. the error is always there, even if  add validation.